# SQL - Aggregate on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a problem and I am new to SQL so I am not sure how to solve it. I have a table with two columns and I want to start at the earliest date and take the next occurrence (of the name column) as the end date.

I know I want to group by Name, but I am not sure what to do after that:

```
 Name     Date
  x      Jan-01    
  y      Feb-01
  z      Mar-01
  x      Jan-02
  y      Feb-02
  z      Mar-02
  x      Jan-03
  y      Feb-03
  z      Mar-03
  x      Jan-04
  y      Feb-04
  z      Mar-04
  x      Jan-05
  y      Feb-05
  z      Mar-05
```

I want the resulting table to look like this:

```
 Name DateStart DateEnd
  x    Jan-01    Jan-02
  y    Feb-01    Feb-02
  z    Mar-01    Mar-02
  x    Jan-03    Jan-04
  y    Feb-03     Feb-04
  z    Mar-03     Mar-04
  x    Jan-05     NULL
  y    Feb-05     NULL       
  z    Mar-05     NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your date column be a proper sortable date and not text, then we can approach this as a gaps and islands problem.  We can use the difference in row numbers method.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Name, MIN(Date) AS DateStart, MAX(Date) AS DateEnd
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY MIN(Date);
```